# python anaconda Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001

Tags: python, anaconda

My first install anaconda today.
I got an error

```
Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001
```

I choose default every setup steps.
When I click any application on anaconda navigator.

- My administrative current language setting is English (USA)

Really sad because just try to learning programming is too hard.

Comment: what is the python script you are going to execute..? can you place the script here . ? here you can find a tutorial about installing anaconda , python on windows https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444

Comment: Hi, I didn't run any script yet. I open anaconda navigator > Home > click Lunch Jupyter notebook  then an error popup occurs.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
 set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```